# REST request for Google Translation API using Retrofit in Android call onFailure every time

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit, google-translation-api

I'm posting my code here:

```
public class APIResponse {

@SerializedName("data")
@Expose
private Data data;

/**
 * No args constructor for use in serialization
 *
 */
public APIResponse() {
}

/**
 *
 * @param data
 */
public APIResponse(Data data) {
    super();
    this.data = data;
}

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}


public class Data {

@SerializedName("translations")
@Expose
private List<Translation> translations = null;

/**
 * No args constructor for use in serialization
 *
 */
public Data() {
}

/**
 *
 * @param translations
 */
public Data(List<Translation> translations) {
    super();
    this.translations = translations;
}

public List<Translation> getTranslations() {
    return translations;
}

public void setTranslations(List<Translation> translations) {
    this.translations = translations;
}
}


public class Translation {

@SerializedName("translatedText")
@Expose
private String translatedText;
@SerializedName("detectedSourceLanguage")
@Expose
private String detectedSourceLanguage;

/**
 * No args constructor for use in serialization
 *
 */
public Translation() {
}

/**
 *
 * @param detectedSourceLanguage
 * @param translatedText
 */
public Translation(String translatedText, String detectedSourceLanguage) {
    super();
    this.translatedText = translatedText;
    this.detectedSourceLanguage = detectedSourceLanguage;
}

public String getTranslatedText() {
    return translatedText;
}

public void setTranslatedText(String translatedText) {
    this.translatedText = translatedText;
}

public String getDetectedSourceLanguage() {
    return detectedSourceLanguage;
}

public void setDetectedSourceLanguage(String detectedSourceLanguage) {
    this.detectedSourceLanguage = detectedSourceLanguage;
}
}
```

The classes APIResponse, Data and Translation are in three different .java files.

This is my REST interface:

```
public interface TranslationRESTInterface {

@POST("?")
public Call<APIResponse> translateWord(@Query("q") String inputWord,
                                       @Query("target") String targetLang,
                                       @Query("key") String apiKey);
}
```

And this is my code to perform the request in my main activity (for the moment, just to verify that everything is working well):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TranslationRESTInterface restInterface;

final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final TextView textViewTranslation = findViewById(R.id.textViewAAA);

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Commons.hostName)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    restInterface = retrofit.create(TranslationRESTInterface.class);

    restInterface.translateWord("house", "it", Commons.apiKey)
            .enqueue(new Callback<APIResponse>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<APIResponse> call, Response<APIResponse> response) {


                    Log.d("out","ok");

                    APIResponse apiResponse = response.body();

                    Data dataResponse = apiResponse.getData();

                    List<Translation> list =
                            dataResponse.getTranslations();

                    String a = list.get(0).getTranslatedText().toString();

                    textViewTranslation.setText(a);

                    Log.d("trad",a);

                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, a ,0);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                            ,0,0);
                    toast.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<APIResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    Log.d("out","fail");

                }
            });

}
}
```

As I can see in the Logcat and in my activity, the Call do not give me a response, after a little bit of time it is always called the method onFailure. 
I've tried to change the POST request in the RESTinterface and other changes but I'm not able to understand where the problem is or where to look.
I really hope some of you could give me a hint!!!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make sure that you can access network. For example make sure that you have proper permission for accesing internet

Comment: I added the internet permission and also tried the app on my phone, thinking that maybe could have been a connection problem of the emulator

Comment: When onFailure() is triggered, check logcat for any clues why it failed (for example exception messages).